# how to keep the same language in two components father and son in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components home.components (father) and room.component.ts (son) in two languages English and Spanish.

when I am in home component in one language and navigate to room component the language selected is the same in both components but when I change the language in room component (son) and navigate to home (father) the language selected is not the same.

how to fix this? with output() and input()? or with angular cycle life???

home.component.ts

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                    <span class="form-inline">
                        <select 
                            class="form-control" 
                            #selectedLang 
                            (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
                          <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
                            [value]="language"
                            [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
                            {{ language }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </span>        

                </ul>

<div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
                        <ng-template #thenBlock>     <p class="title-room">{{ room.title }}</p></ng-template>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock> <p class="title-room">{{ room.titleEs }}</p></ng-template>


switchLang(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.translateEn = language === 'en';
    this.translate.currentLang;
    console.log('current' ,this.translate.currentLang);
  }
```

room.component.ts

```
<div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock3 else elseBlock3"></div>
            <ng-template #thenBlock3>     <p><span class="bold-data">{{'RoomType' | translate}}</span> {{ room.roomtype }}</p></ng-template>
            <ng-template #elseBlock3> <p><span class="bold-data">{{'RoomType' | translate}}</span> {{ room.roomtypeEs }}</p></ng-template>


  switchLang(language: string) {

    this.translate.use(language);
    this.translateEn = language === 'en';
    this.translate.currentLang;
    console.log('current' ,this.translate.currentLang);

}
```

Comment: `this.translate` what is? In case it's just an property of this component, why don't create `TranslateService` as singleton with an observable?

Comment: I tried to create an observable I dont know to fix this

Comment: the problem is the *ngIf in the html. translateEn == true when  the son component is in spanish translateEn should be translateEn == false

Comment: I am using ngx translate library this.translate is the library

Comment: Based on your comment, I'll say you can easily create a `LanguageService` that will help you. I will create an answer for the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that has a `BehaviourSubject` to handle the language set.

LanguageService:

```
@Inject({
  provideIn: "root"
})
export class LanguageService {

  private _language: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  
  constructor (
    private readonly NgxTranslateService: TranslateService
  ) {
    this._language = new BehaviorSubject("EN"); // Default language
    NgxTranslateService.use("EN");
  }

  set language(value: string) {
    this._language.next(value);
    this.NgxTranslateService.use(value);
  }

  public getLanguage$(): Observable<string> {
    return this._language.asObservable();
  }

  public getCurrentLanguage(): string {
    return this._language.getValue();
  }

}
```

In this way, you get the current language as `Observable` or just as a string in order to know which language is currently in use.
I recommend injecting this service in `AppComponent`.

Comment: can you tell me more or less how to use the service?

Comment: Just inject the service in the ‘AppComponent’ in order to have the default language (of course you can customise it as you wish), then where you need to change the language you have to inject it and the use the method ‘set language’